# Create custom extra new field in Magento 1.9 admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom-field

I'm trying to add one more one more field to upload aadhaar card image. I tried doing it by adding attribute but it didn't work,

And also I tried to duplicate the below code in `/app/code/local/customfolder/Customer/sql/codolin_customer_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php` but it didn't work out.

This is the admin panel image I need to add one more field to upload the image

[image]

```
$pCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$pCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($pCustomerEntityType);
$pCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($pCustomerEntityType, $pCustAttributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'upload_pan_image', array(
        'label' => 'Upload PAN Image',
        'input' => 'file',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'forms' => array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'),
        'required' => 0,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup($pCustomerEntityType, $pCustAttributeSetId, $pCustAttributeGroupId, 'upload_pan_image', 0);

$cAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'upload_pan_image');
$cAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_edit','customer_account_create','adminhtml_customer','checkout_register'));
$cAttribute->save();
```

How can I achieve one more field, same as above?